# How to Emulate/Simulate Slow Network to test my web application?

Tags: windows, networking, asp.net

I have built an asp.net application which works well in my network but I am getting complain from users that it doesn't work well in slow network. How to emulate this so that I can test my app on slow network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try WanEm: http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

It allows to configure latency, packet loss, etc.